GCC/clang and Visual C++ structure compatibility issue
I ran into an error in our codebase when mixing compilers.  This happens in a production environment which I work in with a third party library.  I would very much appreciate any insight into how I can fix this.
I have simplified the error to the reproducible example that follows.
The following code produces incompatible structures when compiled with MSVC vs GCC/clang for Windows x64 target.
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;

struct A
{
    u8      u8_1;
    int     i_1;
    __m128  vector_1;
protected:
    bool    b_1;
};

struct B : public A
{
    void*   pv_1;
};

struct C
{
    __m128  vector_1;
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<C>(), "__m128 is NOT POD");
static_assert(!std::is_pod<A>(), "A is POD");

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Size of A: " << sizeof(A) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size of B: " << sizeof(B) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

The MSVC program has this output:
Size of A: 48
Size of B: 64

While GCC/clang programs have the following output:
Size of A: 48
Size of B: 48

According to LLVM/clang documentation, they aim to be ABI compatible with MSVC on Windows but this doesn't appear to be the case.  Is this a bug in LLVM/clang?
Also when I compile with GCC, even using the ms_struct attribute just gives me this error:
error : ms_struct may not produce Microsoft-compatible layouts for classes with base classes or virtual functions [-Wincompatible-ms-struct]

GCC/clang both seem to ignore ms_struct for the layout of struct B.
GodBolt here for easy testing of the bug.
Is there a way to make GCC/clang and MSVC generate the same layout for these structures?

Clang on Windows can run either in msvc-compatible mode or in mingw mode. How are you running it?

I tried using the -mms-bitfields flag which did not work.  Is there something else I should be doing?

I also tried using #pragma ms_struct on but that didn't work either.

Interesting...if A is a POD (to remove the protected: line) the size is as expected. Looking at the implementation of MicrosoftRecordLayoutBuilder (especially the layoutField() part) might tell you something.

Oh.... this is using clang-cl.exe which should be msvc-compatible.

I believe that is because clang only will attempt tail-padding-reuse on non-POD structs.  That's why I added the "protected:" section to duplicate the bug we were seeing.

As that page says, "Clang attempts to be ABI-compatible" (my emphasis), and "Clang’s support for MSVC’s C++ ABI is a work in progress".

The clang MSVC compatibility page claims that the status for ABI compatibility for Record Layout is complete / has been tested with a fuzzer / has no known bugs.  This could be a previously unknown bug though?

GodBolt here for easy verification: https://godbolt.org/z/vxa3jdnas
